# Como fazer isso em LINQ?

Tags: c#

Passei o dia procurando como funciona LINQ e tentei usar em um projetinho que estou usando para estudar, depois de muito tempo tentando o código usando LINQ ficou assim:

```
for (var dia = comeco.Date; dia.Date <= fim.Date; dia = dia.AddDays(1))
        {
            if((from Hospedagem hospedagem in db.Hospedagens.ToList()
               where (hospedagem.DataEntrada <= dia && dia <= hospedagem.DataSaida)
               select hospedagem) != null)
            {
                hospedagens.Concat((from Hospedagem hospedagem in db.Hospedagens.ToList()
                                    where (hospedagem.DataEntrada <= dia && dia <= hospedagem.DataSaida)
                                    select hospedagem).ToList());
            }

        }
        if (hospedagens != null)
        {
            hospedagens = hospedagens.GroupBy(x => x.HospedagemID).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
        }
```

Mas não funcionou, então fiz usando foreach, assim funcionou:

```
        List<Hospedagem> lista = db.Hospedagens.ToList();
        List<Hospedagem> hospedagens = new List<Hospedagem>();
        for (var dia = comeco.Date; dia.Date <= fim.Date; dia = dia.AddDays(1))
        {
            foreach (Hospedagem h in lista)
            {
                if (h.DataEntrada <= dia && dia <= h.DataSaida)
                {
                        hospedagens.Add(h);
                }
            }
        }
        if (hospedagens != null)
        {
            hospedagens = hospedagens.GroupBy(x => x.HospedagemID).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
        }
```

queria entender o por que do primeiro código não funcionar e como que eu poderia corrigir os problemas dele.

Comment: Você está usando EF? Está pegando os dados do DB, transformando um lista e fazendo a seleção? Se for isso faz em LINQ que fica melhor. Não que fique bom, o certo é usar o LINQ para gerar uma consulta SQL no banco e trazer já filtrado, mas aí o código tem que ser totalmente outro, e nem tem informação suficiente para ajudar.

Comment: sim estou usando EF, a idéia é pegar da classe de hospedagem (uma classe que relaciona um cliente com um quarto e tem propriedades de data de entrada e saída) e com dois valores de data passadas por parametro (comeco e fim)  fazer a seleção de somente as hospedagens que estão dentro desse periodo de tempo.

Answer (score 0):

Se quer só o que está dentro do for, ficaria assim:

```
List<Hospedagem> hospedagens = new List<Hospedagem>();

for (var dia = comeco.Date; dia.Date <= fim.Date; dia = dia.AddDays(1))
{
    hospedagens.AddRange(from h in db.Hospedagens where h.DataEntrada <= dia && dia <= h.DataSaida select h);
}

if (hospedagens != null)
{
    hospedagens = hospedagens.GroupBy(x => x.HospedagemID).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
}
```

Seu código não funciona porque o concat não modifica a lista, ele retorna uma nova, no seu caso o melhor seria usar o AddRange.